# Default to an empty array whenever column is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Like the title says, I would like to set a model's default value to an empty array whenever it's nil. Is there any ideal way to do this? The fields are serialize in the db, should be an array at all times.

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
before_validation :set_defaults

def set_defaults
    some_field ||= []
    other_field ||= []
end
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you wish to have an empty array as a default column values? That isn't correct to assign an empty array to value of DB column, because it must be specifically serialized. Instead define methods in model, which will return empty array for specific column:

```
def some_field
   read_attribute(:some_field) || []
end

def other_field
   read_attribute(:other_field) || []
end
```

But **better way** is to define that methods not in model, but in a serializer or decorator.